# nginx as proxy for WebSocket: inspect and block certain requests

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js, fail2ban, websocket

I ran NodeJS as a kind of Webapplication Server serving an AngularJS frontend. They communicate solely over WebSockets, using the SailsJS implementation of Socket.IO. Between frontend (client) and the NodeJS backend, sits nginx as a proxy, configured like so:

```
server {
    listen 1337 ssl;
    location /socket.io/ {
       proxy_pass https://localhost:1338;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

So far, so good. I now want to monitor and secure the Websocket connection. In particular, I want to prevent XSS attacks and exclude IPs trying to brute force the login to my application.
I'm pretty new to that stuff but after some research I came across fail2ban and nginx-naxsi which might be exactly what I need. However, I have no idea how I can make them work with my setup.

Is this even possible? Can I somehow intercept the traffic tunneled through a Websocket in the proxy (being nginx)?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't have any experience with fail2ban or nginx-naxsi, but I do know that **ModSecurity is avaiable for nginx since 2012** and is easily capable of handling your requests. It is open source as well so it can be customized for your needs.

**ModSecurity includes base_rulesets and optional_rulesets with already prepared & ready-to-use XSS- and DOS-rules to secure your server.**

It definitely causes a slight bump in your performance (depending on how many rules you use and how much traffic you handle), but is a really **powerful tool**.

Here is a [tutorial](https://geekflare.com/install-modsecurity-on-nginx/) on how to set it up for nginx. Maybe you'll like that :)

Comment: Thanks for that hint! However, are you sure that ModSecurity works for proxied Websocket connections? I have found anything about that in their docs and the only issue I've found on github is rather discouraging.

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't read your initial question well enough, sorry for that. Because I didn't remember the websocket-part -.- I have no idea if ModSec is able to read that traffic. I mean, it is open source, so there's probably a way to do it, but I agree: the other posts concerned with this topic are rather discouraging.

Answer (score 0):

naxsi and fail2ban are different
naxsi is a WAF (web application firewall), this means that all requests first go through naxsi, then you will have some rules set to check each request, in case the client made a request to a resource you don't want to grant access, then naxsi will block that request

fail2ban is an IDS (intrusion detection system), what fail2ban does is it monitors your `nginx logs` (or any log for the matter), and based on some REGEX you can block clients after certain attempts. so let's say you have a brute force attack where the client is attempting to reach unexistent URLS, then fail2ban will detect that that client has a lot of 404 responsed, then it will ban the ip

so naxsi denies malicious requests and fail2ban just bans in case a condition is met

Comment: Well, thanks for the info. However, first problem: fail2ban monitors the logs - my web socket traffic doesn't appear right now in the nginx logs. How can I turn logging on here? Second problem: naxsi blocks some requests based on rules - e.g. block all "POST" requests, however nginx is, as of my current configuration, complete ignorant regarding the used method inside the websocket traffic. It's established via a GET request - nginx doesn't seem to care about the rest. Do you know what to do here?